# Swift Hard Functions

Tags: swift, function

I was searching about how to get the Dictionary key from value

And I Found this :

```
    func allKeysForValue<K, V : Equatable>(dict: [K : V], val: V) -> [K] {
            return dict.filter{ $0.1 == val }.map{ $0.0 }
    }
```

It's work but I don't know how it's work , what K and V means
, I know that's mean key and value but how the method work  , What `allKeysForValue<K, V : Equatable>` mean ?

Comment: "Generics". See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Comment: Thank you @moritz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`K` and `V` are generic parameters of a [generic function](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html).

This makes `allKeysForValue` a function that can take any kind of dictionary with some constraints. The key type of the dictionary is `K` and the value type is `V`. The constraint here is that `V` must conform to `Equatable`. This is important because we are going to use the `==` operator on two `V`types:

```
$0.1 == val
```

Without this constraint, we cannot guarantee that `V` has a `==` operator.

For an example, if I pass a `[String, Int]` dictionary to this function, `K` will be `String` and `V` will be `Int`.

To describe what this function does, it takes a dictionary d and a value v, filters d, leaving every KVP that has a value of v, then transforms each KVP into just the key, returning the array of keys.

Comment: I search about generic but your explain is the best , thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

It means the dictionnary Keys are from class `K`, and values are from class `V`. MoreOver the `V : Equatable` means each value class of your dict conforms to `Equatable` protocol.

Finally the `-> [K]` means the `func` returns an `Array` conteningm elements of class `K` ( ie the keys list )